# Troubleshooting Active Directory Account Lockouts

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts

I have 10 users where their AD accounts keep getting locked out.

I have been using Netwrix Account Lockout Examiner to watch when one of the 10 user accounts is locked.  I keep seeing the Bad Pwd Count increase, until they hit the Account Lockout threshold.

I am trying to figure out where these invalid password attempts are coming from.

I have done the following:

1. Enabled NetLogon Debug on the DCs
2. Enabled Advanced Audit Policy > Account Management > Audit User Account Management on the DCs GPO.
3. Enabled Advanced Audit Policy > Logon/Logoff > Audit Account Lockout on the DCs GPO.
4. Enabled Advanced Audit Policy > Audit Logon on the DCs GPO.
5. Enabled Security Settings > Local Policies > Audit Policy > Audit Logon Events on each of the local computers.
6. Enabled Security Settings > Local Policies > Audit Policy > Audit Account Logon Events on each of the local computers.

Been scanning the Event Logs on the local machines and on the DCs for various event IDs that I found while googling this issue...but I don't see any obvious correlation between when a Bad Pwd Count is recorded and an associated event in the log.

Searched through the NetLogon Debug log looking for bad password attempts and found nothing.  I looked at the scheduled tasks on several of the computers, but none run being run around the same time as a Bad Pwd Count.  The network shares are mapped via GPO and membership in security groups.

I see several Event 4771 (Kerberos pre-authentication failed.) for a handful of the users experiencing this issue, but not all of them.

I am not sure where to look next.  Any suggestions?

Thanks
jlimited